# How to write in Telugu language in Ubuntu without using Google input tools extension?

Tags: language-support, input-language

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04. I want to write in Telugu language in gedit or some other text editors.
Somehow writing in the browser using google input tools extension and then copying whole text into the text editor is tedious.
Is there any way I could write Telugu language in Ubuntu itself without using chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Language Support" from the dash and this window will open:
[image: 1]

Click on "Install/Remove Languages" and add Telugu as shown below

[image: 2]

Now go to Languages within Settings and press the add button to add a language. Select telugu and your preferred form of input

[image: 3]

After you add it, there'll be a language selector on the top right, allowing you to type in whichever language you want anywhere on Ubuntu